# Get child window handles in C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-messages, window-handles

I'm starting a process in C# and then sending Windows messages to that process with SendMessage.  Usually I send the messages to Process.MainWindowHandle, but in some instances I might need to find a child window handle and send messages there instead.  How would I do that in C# and what are the options for finding child windows (i.e. do a need to know the name of the window or are there other options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [EnumChildWindows](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html) (pinvoke.net)