# Send Win API paste cmd from background C# app

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, winforms-interop

**Goal**: write a C# app that runs in the background, listens for the key combination Win-V, and when that occurs, pastes the clipboard contents into the current active window (some arbitrary app). Essentially I'm trying to mimic [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/), but I'm not bothering to convert the text to plain text first.

**Problem**: pasting into the currently active windows is not working.

**Details**: To listen in the background for key presses I'm using the *globalKeyboardHook* class from [A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook). I'm able to catch Win-V events, but I'm not able to send the paste command properly. I can send the paste by using the functions **SendKeys.Send** or **keybd_event**. However, they send another "V" press down the pipeline which gets caught by the **gkh_KeyDown** event and causes multiple paste events to fire.

I'm expecting that I need to use **SendMessage** or **PostMessage**, but all my attempts to do that have failed so far. Below is the full code with the last function, **SendCtrlV**, being the one of interest. The comments explain everything I've tried so far. Can you see what I'm missing?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Utilities;

namespace KeyHookTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool LWin_down;
        private bool V_down;
        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static public extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.V);
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.LWin);
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
        }

        void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LWin)
                LWin_down = false;
            else
                V_down = false;
        }

        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LWin)
                LWin_down = true;
            else
                V_down = true;

            if (LWin_down && V_down)
            {
                LogDebug("Enter Win+V");

                try
                {
                    SendCtrlV();
                }
                catch { }
            }

        }

        private void SendCtrlV()
        {
            uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
            int KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
            int KEYUP = 0x0101;
            byte KEY_LCONTROL1 = 0x11;
            IntPtr KEY_LCONTROL2 = new IntPtr(0x11);
            byte KEY_V1 = 0x56;
            IntPtr KEY_V2 = new IntPtr(0x56);
            int WM_PASTE1 = 0x302;
            uint WM_PASTE2 = 0x302;

            IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

            // Works, but causes multiple gkh_KeyDown to fire so it's slow and buggy
            /*keybd_event(KEY_LCONTROL1, 0, 0, 0);
            keybd_event(KEY_V1, 0, 0, 0);
            keybd_event(KEY_V1, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            keybd_event(KEY_LCONTROL1, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);*/

            // Works, but causes multiple gkh_KeyDown to fire so it's slow and buggy
            //SendKeys.Send("^v");

            // Doesn't work, causes UAC prompt
            //SendKeys.Send("{^}v");

            // Doesn't work, nothing gets pasted to the foregroundwindow
            //SendMessage(hWnd, WM_PASTE1, 0, 0);

            // Doesn't work, nothing gets pasted to the foregroundwindow
            //PostMessage(hWnd, WM_PASTE2, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

            // Doesn't work, nothing gets pasted to the foregroundwindow
            /*SendMessage(hWnd, KEYDOWN, KEY_LCONTROL1, 0);
            SendMessage(hWnd, KEYDOWN, KEY_V1, 0);
            SendMessage(hWnd, KEYUP, KEY_V1, 0);
            SendMessage(hWnd, KEYUP, KEY_LCONTROL1, 0);*/

            // Doesn't work, nothing gets pasted to the foregroundwindow
            /*PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0100, KEY_LCONTROL2, IntPtr.Zero);
            PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0100, KEY_V2, IntPtr.Zero);
            PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0101, KEY_V2, IntPtr.Zero);
            PostMessage(hWnd, 0x0101, KEY_LCONTROL2, IntPtr.Zero);*/
        }

        private void LogDebug(string msg)
        {
            string logpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + @"\Desktop\KeyHookTest.txt";
            File.AppendAllText(logpath, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + ": " + msg + "\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, you don't send the `WM_PASTE` message to a window handle; you send it to the handle of the control you want to paste the content into directly. You have to use `EnumChildWindows` on the `hWnd` you get from `GetForegroundWindow` to find that control's handle. (You don't paste into a window itself, but into an edit control on the window.)

Comment: That certainly would make sense. With some quick searching on that I haven't found much on how to do that, but I'll keep looking in that direction.

Comment: If you check the docs for `EnumChildWindows`, given the code you've written so far I doubt you'll have too much trouble figuring it out (definitely more easily than I could in C# - in C or Delphi it's easy <g>). BTW, +1 for the question - I was so busy writing the comment that I forgot to do it the first time around. :-)

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumChildWindows.html) will help. I got it from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1456353/62576).

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646605/how-to-paste-text-using-windows-paste-command-to-other-application-in-c

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These additional links helped lead me to the answer:

- [How to get active child window](http://www.readusenet.com/windows-all-win32/1132349-how-to-get-active-child-window.html)
- [How can I find the active child window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413721/how-can-i-find-the-active-child-window)

Here's what's working for me:

```
private void SendCtrlV()
{
    IntPtr hWnd = GetFocusedHandle();
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_PASTE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}

static IntPtr GetFocusedHandle()
{
    var info = new GuiThreadInfo();
    info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
    if (!GetGUIThreadInfo(0, ref info))
        throw new Win32Exception();
    return info.hwndFocus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you must use the TextBox's native window handle if you want it to be effective